# Cross Platform Developments

Tags: qt, cross-platform

Well, I need your advice.

I'm working on a huge engineering project, everything is ready now (resources and formulas etc) and it's time to start coding. I don't have any problem with what language to code with (i know a lot).
but they're the users who are pulling me off.
I use Windows as a primary OS but there are a lot of Mac and Linux users too. And these days tablets have taken a lot of developing space ( Android and stuff).

So what option do you advice :

1)Write the program from the scratch on each OS, I mean writing the program on Windows using Visual Studio, on Mac use Xcode.
but this costs a lot ... I own Windows PC, buying Mac or Mac OS for my desktop, will ruin my budget.

2)Use cross-platform compilers ...
  It is nice. but how about the commercial use? I have read that I need to buy a commercial license in order to publish my apps worldwide.
please if this is wrong tell me about it.

so really I don't know ... shall I just deploy it for Windows?
Also if you know a great option for cross-compiling would help a lot .

Your Advice Is Appreciated

Best Regards

Comment: Would it work as a web application? That would be pretty cross-platform. If not, Java would be a good language to check out...

Comment: Actually, Java would work well for web application development as well.

Comment: hmmm java is nice, but what about the JVM that must be installed on every os.

Comment: You will need a JVM anyways, if it is a desktop app. If it is a web-based app, (using Servlets), then no JVM is needed. I'm not a huge fan of JAVA, but it is what it is.

Comment: To your second question: Nokia has licensed it under the Lower GNU GPL: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.1.html and http://qt.nokia.com/products/licensing. This is mentioned in this press release and apply to QT 4.5+ : http://qt.nokia.com/about/news/lgpl-license-option-added-to-qt/. There is a commercially-licensed QT at http://www.digia.com/en/Qt/, but I didn't look into it any further.

Comment: Yeah LGPL is nice , i think i will use QT . thanks for your time

Comment: If it is a desktop app, you should also look at Xojo. It builds native Windows, Mac and Linux apps from a single source project. http://www.xojo.com

Answer (score 1):

What kind of app is it?

If it's just a number crunching app with a very simple front end then can you write a commandline version and wrap it with a web script?

If it needs very responive rich user interface and you can program in C++ then Qt is a very good solution even if you don't need cross platform.

The LGPL license is perfectly suitable for commercial apps.

Comment: Yeah Qt seems nice , i need to package needed qt framework libs with my app folder right ?